# Prove that $XY$ crosses the midpoints

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$\triangle ABC$ has altitudes $AD$, $BE$, $CF$. The reflections of $E$, $F$ in $H$ are $E'$, $F'$. The circle $DE'F'$ intersects $BE$, $CF$ at $X$, $Y$. Prove that $XY$ goes through the midpoints of $AB$, $AC$.

I can show that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$ by simply angle-chasing. $EYFX$ is cyclic as well as $APFY$. [image]

I also tried showing that $AP$=$PH+HD$

Comment: This is a nice hard problem, it is a very good experience e.g. when training or when searching adequate material for training for a contest, such as a higher level olympiad for a lower level of mathematical knowledge. Please, which is the source (and the level as it was set by the source)? It is really a pitty that the question did not get the deserved attention from the community. I put a plus one in there...

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the idea of the solution, consider the following picture first, where the mid points $B_1$, $C_1$ of $CA$, $AB$, and the reflection $D'$ of $D$ in $H$ are also present.

[image: math stackexchange question 2598445]

We want to show that the points $X,H,D,B_1$ are on a cycle. This would be enough to conclude, since from here we are allowed to write the first equality in the following chain:
$$
\widehat{XB_1D} =
180^\circ - \widehat{XHD} =
\widehat{XHA} =
\widehat{EHA} =
\widehat{EFA} =
\hat C=
\widehat{B_1DC} \ .
$$
This gives $XB_1\|DC=BC$. Similarly $YC_1\|BC$. And now combine this with $XY\|BC$ obtained by the pink angle chasing from the picture, to obtain the collinearity of $B_1,C_1,X,Y$.

So let us show that $(XHDB_1)$ is cyclic by considering the two marked angles in $X$ and $B_1$ against the (*a posteriori* insured) arc $\overset\frown{HD}$. The angle in $X$ is complicated, but we will move it to a simple place via:
$$
\hat X = 
\widehat{E'XD} =
\widehat{E'F'D} =
\widehat{EFD'} \ .
$$
So we need to clear
$$\widehat{EFD'} \overset ?=
\widehat{HB_1D}\ .
$$
After adding the same angle,
$\widehat{EFD} = 2\widehat{EFH}=2(90^\circ-\hat C)=\widehat{DB_1C}$, on both sides, we have to clear equivalently:
$$
\widehat{D'FD} \overset ?=
\widehat{HB_1C}\ .
$$
And indeed, let us show the similarity of triangles $\Delta D'FD\sim\Delta HB_1C$. First of all, we clear an angle,
$$
\widehat{FDD'} =
\widehat{FDA} =
\widehat{FCA} =
\widehat{HCB_1}\ .
$$
It remains to get a proportion, and this is:
$$
\frac{D'D}{HC} = 
2\cdot \frac{HD}{HC} = 2\cos B
=2\cdot\frac{BD}{BA}
=2\cdot\frac{DF}{AC} 
% \text{ from }\Delta BDF\sim\Delta BAC
= \frac{DF}{AC/2}
= \frac{DF}{CB_1}\ .
$$
$\square$

Answer (score -2):

Take point $C$ as the origin of a Cartesian coordinate system. Then let $|PD|=a$. It suffices to note that since the line $XPY$ is parallel to the base of the triangle, its equation is $y=a$. Now since the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ have coordinates $(x_1,a)$ and $(x_2,a)$ respectively, it's clear that they lie on the line of interest. $\square$

Comment: Could someone explain the error?

Comment: How do you know that the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ have coordinates $(x1,a)$ and $(x2,a)$?

Comment: We know the length of the segments, so we know their midpoints. This should be clear. I only omitted stating the x-coordinates explicitly because they eventually don't matter.

Comment: Of course, bot how do you know that the $y$ coordinate is $a$, the same as that of $P$?

Comment: @Aretino Say half of $|AC|$ is $\alpha$ and half of $|AB|$ is $\beta$ then circles with radii $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and centered at $B$ and $C$ respectively will interest the lines through $AC$ and $AB$ at their midpoints. The positive solutions of the equations connecting these circles and the lines through the sides are the coordinates sought.